True or False problem regarding the solution set of a linear system of equations
In the textbook Linear Algebra and Its Applications by Lays, there is a question asking the reader to decide if the following statement is True.

The solution set of a linear system involving variables $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ is a list
of numbers $(s_1, \ldots, s_n)$ that makes each equation in the system a true statement
when the values $s_1, \ldots, s_n$ are substituted for $x_1, \ldots, x_n$, respectively.

I think this is pretty much what a solution means.
However, someone disagrees with me by saying:

(This) statement is false, because the solution set should be the set of the list(s) of numbers that satisfies the description, not a list of numbers

What do you think? I don't have access to the solution manual of the book. So I am not sure what the author's intention is.

I would agree with the disagreer.

There is no guarantee that the solution is unique. The solution set might be  empty, or might be infinite.  In the latter case it is usually written in terms of one or more arbitrary parameters, e.g. $[x_1 = 2 + 3 s, ; x_2 = 3 + 4 s]$, where any number can be substituted for $s$ to get a solution.

@RobertIsrael You mean since the solution set is empty the statement should be false?

The issue is singular vs. not necessarily singular.

It is the difference between a solution and the solution set.

The answer becomes obvious when I consider it like this :: "the Solution Set must be a Set of [a list of ....]" versus "the Solution Set is a list of [....]" :: I will then realize that Set is not list in general.

What you have defined is a solution. So, the following is correct:

A solution of a linear system involving variables $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ is a list
of numbers $(s_1, \ldots, s_n)$ that makes each equation in the system a true statement
when the values $s_1, \ldots, s_n$ are substituted for $x_1, \ldots, x_n$, respectively.

Then, the solution set is the set of ALL the solutions of the system.
Hope this helps. :)
